# Как убрать отображение содержимого папки home на рабочем столе?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Такая проблема: внезапно стало отображаться содержимое папки home на рабочем столе, отчего последний напоминает столб с объявлениями. Это не ссылки, а именно файлы и папки. У меня Ubuntu 14.04. Кстати, прикрепил скриншот, где видно, что папка "Домашняя папка" и "Рабочий стол" имеют один и тот же адрес.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настройках файлового менеджера Наутилуса нет пункта меню (советовали в сети) "Отображение содержимого Домашнего каталога на Рабочем столе" и ничего похожего. В Ubuntu Tweak Tool раздел "Рабочий стол" также отсутствует. Да и переюзал уже это давно - не помогает.

Смотрел файл ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Загрузки"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Документы"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Музыка"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Изображения"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Видео"
```

Как исправить положение?

Comment: так попробуйте XDG_DESKTOP_DIR направить в нужное место

Comment: Не помогает. Файл ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs после перезагрузки системы принимает свой прежний вид.

Comment: Покажите содержимое `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf`. и `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

файл `~/.config/user-dirs.dir` о котором шла речь должен иметь первую строку:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Рабочий стол"
```

а в представленном варианте она:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
```

в этом случае все содержимое домашней папки будет дублироваться на рабочем столе.